# preserving database when upgrading sonarqube to different helm chart

Tags: sonarqube, helm3

I currently have the sonarqube application deployed using helm, and I originally used the chart found at https://oteemo.github.io/charts. However, this has now been deprecated and I wish to now use the helm chart at https://SonarSource.github.io/helm-chart-sonarqube. In my old deployment of sonarqube,there was a database that had data in it. So my question is, when I deploy sonarqube again using the new helm chart, using the following commands:

```
helm repo add sonarqube https://SonarSource.github.io/helm-chart-sonarqube
helm repo update
kubectl create namespace sonarqube
helm upgrade --install -n sonarqube sonarqube sonarqube/sonarqube
```

will this override the data I had in my database as part of the old helm release? If so, what steps should I take to ensure the data is preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the configuration data during helm install as given here: https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#customizing-the-chart-before-installing

I checked the sources for the **sonarqube** chart that you are using from here: https://sonarsource.github.io/helm-chart-sonarqube/ and it had a link to the source to be here: https://github.com/SonarSource/helm-chart-sonarqube, which has [values.yaml](https://github.com/SonarSource/helm-chart-sonarqube/blob/master/charts/sonarqube/values.yaml#L324) with support for persistence. With this support you either need create your own [Persistent Volume Claim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) and use the --set command as below:

```
helm upgrade --install -n sonarqube sonarqube sonarqube/sonarqube \
--set persistence.enabled=true,persistence.existingClaim=<your claim name>
```

Or you need to create a default [Storage Class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) in your Kubernetes cluster and simply use command below:

```
helm upgrade --install -n sonarqube sonarqube sonarqube/sonarqube \
--set persistence.enabled=true
```

If you enable persistence then your SonarQube data will be preserved and you will be able to use when the pod or node crashes or when you are upgrading the chart to use a new SonarQube version.